# How can use sameAs property

Tags: ontology, dbpedia, protege

I'm using Protege 4.3 to develop my ontology that will include some things that are already described in DBpedia. I read here that I have to use sameAs property, but I could not know how can I do it in protege. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instances, go to the "individual" tab, "description" frame, there's "Same Individual As". There you can see, add and remove individuals that are SameAs others.

[image: protege individual tab zoom-in]